# Gradient of a function w.r.t. matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Let $ \varphi : \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times m} \to \mathbb{R} $ be defined by

$$ \varphi(x, A, B) = \left \| \left( x^T A B \right)^T - x \right \|^2 $$

What are the gradients of $\varphi$ with respect to $A$ and $B$, $\nabla_A \varphi(x, A, B) $ and $\nabla_B \varphi(x, A, B)$?

---

I have reached the followings. Are they correct?

$$
\nabla_A \varphi(x, A, B) = 2 ((x^TAB)^T - x)x^TB^T
$$

$$
\nabla_B \varphi(x, A, B) = 2 ((x^TAB)^T - x)x^TA^T
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost correct!
Define
$\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$
and
$\mathbf{u}=\mathbf{C}^T\mathbf{x} - \mathbf{x}$

$$
\phi = \left \| \mathbf{u} \right \|^2
$$
thus
$
d\phi 
= 2 \mathbf{u} :d\mathbf{u}
= 2 \mathbf{x}\mathbf{u}^T :d\mathbf{C}
$.
From here, you find
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{A}}
= 2 \mathbf{x} (\mathbf{Bu})^T ,
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \mathbf{B}}
= 2 (\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{u}^T
$$
which are both matrices of the correct dimensions.

Comment: $+\tt1$ This is undoubtedly correct, but it's so terse that a new contributor might not be able to fill in the missing steps.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to expand the difference $\varphi(x, A+H, B) - \varphi(x, A, B) $ and express it as the sum of a linear transformation on variable $H$ and a nonlinear transformation on variable $H$. This linear transformation is equal to the trace between $\nabla_{A}\varphi(x, A, B)$ and $H$. More precisely,
$$
\varphi(x, A+H, B) - \varphi(x, A, B) = \text{trace}(\nabla_{A}\varphi(x, A, B)\cdot H^T) +\rho(H) \quad \mbox{ and } \quad \lim_{H\to 0}\dfrac{\rho(H)}{H}=0
$$

Note that
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x, A, B) &= \|x^T A B - x\|^2_F 
\\
&= \text{trace}\left((x^T A B - x)(x^T A B - x)^T\right) 
\\
&= \text{trace}\left(x^T A B B^T A^T x - x^T A B x - x B^T A^T x + xx^T\right) \\
&= \text{trace}\left(x^T A B B^T A^T x\right) - 2\text{trace}\left(x^T A B x\right) + \text{trace}\left(xx^T\right)
\end{align*}
After some algebraic manipulations you will find
\begin{align*}
\varphi(x, A+H, B) - \varphi(x, A, B) 
= &
\text{trace}\left(x^T A B B^T H^T x\right) 
\\ +& 
\text{trace}\left(x^T H B B^T A^T x\right) 
\\&- 2\text{trace}\left(x^T H B x\right) 
\\
&\quad   +\text{trace}\left(x^T H B B^T H^T x\right)\\
\end{align*}

Let $M_1, M_2, \ldots, M_k$ be a sequence of matrices that are compatible for multiplication, meaning the number of columns of matrix $M_\ell$ is equal to the number of rows of matrix $M_{\ell+1}$ for $\ell = 1, 2, \ldots, k-1$, and the number of columns of matrix $M_k$ is equal to the number of rows of matrix $M_1$. Then,

- $\text{trace}(M_1 M_2 \ldots M_k) = \text{trace}(M_2 M_3 \ldots M_k M_1) =  \cdots = \text{trace}(M_k M_1 M_2 \ldots M_{k-1})$,
- $\text{trace}(M_\ell)=\text{trace}(M_\ell^T)$,
- $(M_{1}\cdot M_{2})^{T}=M_{2}^{T}\cdot M_{1}^{T}$,  $(M_{1}\cdot M_{2}\cdot M_{3})^{T}=M_{3}^{T}\cdot M_{2}^{T}\cdot M_{1}^{T}$ and  $(M_1\cdot M_2\cdot \ldots \cdot M_k)^{T}= M_k^T\cdot M_{k-1}^T\cdot \ldots \cdot M_1^T $

Using these three properties above you will get
$$
\nabla_{A}\varphi(x,A,B)= 2x(B(B^TA^Tx-x))^T
$$

Comment: Thank's a lot !

Comment: @Rabist The MathStackExchange community encourages you to give a +1 vote (in the top left corner of each answer) if the answer was helpful to you.

Comment: I did that. You helped me a lot. I would appreciate it if you could help me with this [final problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4679558/gradient-of-vectors-and-matrices-multiplication).